# Cannot satisfy ZodTuple type signature with mapped Tuple type

Tags: typescript, tuples, inference, mapped-types, zod

I'm experiencing a compilation failure when trying to satisfy `ZodTuple`, when using a mapped tuple derived from an original tuple definition. See the compilation error in a [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3gLQgEwCoCuYANigDRzb7IoCCAdogL5wBmUEIcARAF67cA3AChhSVJVyESKAJI4U9GMCQAePHBQAPGIpwBnSfiKlVAbSp4aDRBQB0Dy9cZmAuq4B8HuAF44G7V16AyNpU2B6VhQoOAARFFZvAH5QkxRVdDMAazgIuCyURAhWOITXAC5S1mzXJm9K%20hQAN2i4QSA)

Below is a trivial example of a mapped tuple type, in which the mapped tuple OUGHT to be the same exact type as the original I believe.

```
import type {ZodTuple, ZodTypeAny} from "zod";

type ZodTupleIdentity<T extends ZodTuple<[ZodTypeAny, ...ZodTypeAny[]]>> = T extends ZodTuple<infer Def> ? ZodTuple<{[k in keyof Def]: Def[k]}> : never ;
```

However, this raises the error `Type '{ [k in keyof Def]: Def[k]; }' is not assignable to type '[ZodTypeAny, ...ZodTypeAny[]]'` which suggests I can't even define a ZodTuple using the same tuple definition as it started with.

Of course in a real case I would do something to CHANGE the entries so I can transform one validated tuple type into another based on it (e.g. same length, mapped members).

However, even passing on the exact same entries in the mapped tuple does not work without compiler errors so I must be doing something wrong.

I'm expecting mapped types over tuples to work as per https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html

How can I create a mapped type from the inferred generic argument, that will fulfil the generic argument signature of ZodTuple?